# How to save the response from an asynchronous call to variable

Tags: javascript, api

I have a API call and I expected to write response to `friends` variable.

```
getFriends = function() {
  return VK.Api.call('friends.get', {}, function(response) {
    if (response.response)
      response.response;
  });
};

var friends = getFriends();
console.log(friends)  // undefined;
```

In [my previous question one guy told me that I can fix it with callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542292/how-to-return-result-of-function?noredirect=1#comment49157726_30542292) function and close my question. I implement a callback but again I can't get a response.

```
var getFriends = function(callbackFn) {
  return VK.Api.call('friends.get', {}, function(response) {
    if (response.response) {
      callbackFn(response.response);
    }
  });
};

var friends = getFriends(function(list) { return list; });
```

How I can write `response.response` to variable for a lot of next manipulations?

Comment: You **must** read the answer of the question we link to. You **can't** just return the value from your function which gets it with an asynchronous call.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I read what I need a callback function. You **must** read the my question. I write about it in second paragraph

Comment: you must read the whole answer, not just one sentence. There is no way to code in JavaScript without understanding this fundamental problem.

Comment: @DenysSéguret but is it good way to close question without helpful answer?

Comment: This question is asked many times a day. We built very complete answers like the one I linked you to so that you can read them instead of the bad incomplete ones like the one below.

Answer (score -2):

It's actually much simpler

```
var friends = null;
VK.Api.call('friends.get', {}, function(response) {
    if (response.response) {
      friends = response.response;

      console.log(friends);
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely, you are joking, because `friends` is `null`.

Comment: @bob it will be null initially, make sure you are logging it in the callback and not the outer scope. Data will become available when the response is received.

Comment: But how I can check that the response is received? I have a lot of buttons in DOM for manipulating with response.

Comment: @bob the callback is how you check

Comment: What's up with the down-votes